# all file names are strange or "corrupted" in time machine backup

Tags: backup, time-machine

My father bought a new computer and is trying to restore from a time machine backup of the old computer on an external drive. I am helping him using a remote screen view by skype.

On the external TM drive there is a standard looking Backups.backupdb folder, with a large number of dated backups below it. Meaning (saying from memory, because I do not have easy access to the machine) something like approximately:

```
/Volumes/TM/Backups.backupdb/Dad's Mac/2018-07-03-214530/Macintosh HD/Users/simone
/Volumes/TM/Backups.backupdb/Dad's Mac/2018-07-02-010500/Macintosh HD/Users/simone
etc.
```

However, when navigating to the user's actual folder (using the Finder), all of the filenames are unrecognizable and have weird characters.

What would casuse this?

Since the overall folder structure is reasonable, my first thought is that the data is maybe ok but this is some sort of locale or *character encoding* mismatch between the old and new computers?

Comment: not as an answer to your question just sharing. I use an app called TeamViewer (installed on both sides), which allows me to actually control the other computer. It is a Free app.

Comment: Have you used Apple's Migration Assistant app to restore the Time machine backup to the new Mac yet? Do you see the odd filenames on files that have been restored or only on the Time Machine volume?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of those filenames with unrecognizable characters, or even better, a screenshot?